# Getting a tooltip in a user control to show databound text and stay open

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, tooltip

I have a user control that shows a `TextBox` along with a small help icon.

My goal is to have a `ToolTip` pop-up, show some databound text and stay open when the mouse hovers over the help icon.

So, to that end I have created a HelpText dependency property in the user control allowing me to bind a help text string to the user control.

So, my user control looks something like this

```
<UserControl Name="textField" ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=textField,Path=Text}"/>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource Help.Icon}">
            <Image.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding ElementName=textField,Path=HelpText}"/>
            </Image.ToolTip>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

This code does show the tooltip, except that it is empty! Also, the StaysOpen property does not make any difference as the tooltip shuts down after a few seconds.

Funny thing is that when I set the same binding directly on the Image control's ToolTip property the bound text is shown allright in the tooltip pop-up, however it still does not stay open:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource Help.Icon}" ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=textField,Path=HelpText}">
```

So my to questions are:

1. How come the binding against the user control's HelpText dependency property does not work in the first code sample but does work in the second?
2. How do I make the `ToolTip` stay open or rather how do I make the `ToolTip` both stay open and show the databound text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

ToolTips are not part of the same VisualTree as the rest of your XAML, so the `DataContext` is not inherited the way you would expect it to be.

Writing `ToolTip="{Binding SomeProperty}"` will automatically set the ToolTip's `DataContext` to `SomeProperty`, however if you build a custom ToolTip you must do this yourself.

```
<ToolTip DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ... />
```

This will bind the ToolTip's `DataContext` to the `DataContext` of whatever object the ToolTip is on.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, your `<ToolTip>` would probably look like this, since `PlacementTarget` would be your `Image`:

```
<!-- Could also use something like Tag if DataContext is actually used -->
<Image DataContext="{Binding ElementName=textField, Path=HelpText}" 
       Source="{StaticResource Help.Icon}">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

As for why it won't stay open, I'm not positive but it might be because the [ToolTipService.ShowDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showduration.aspx) property defaults to 5 seconds, and that probably overwrites the `StaysOpen` property.

You can try setting it to something higher, such as

```
<Image ToolTipService.ShowDuration="60000" ... />
```

Or you can try [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620580/302677) of using a `Popup` styled to look like a `ToolTip` instead. The code would probably look something like this:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyImage}" 
       IsOpen="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=MyImage, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=textField, Path=HelpText}" />
</Popup>
```

Comment: Why you think PlacementTarget would be UserControl? I think it is Image in his case, isn't it?

Comment: @LPL You are correct, I mistakenly thought the ToolTip was on the UserControl when I was first writing the answer, and I forgot to update the code sample when I noticed it was on the Image instead of the UserControl. It's updated now, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It cleared a few things up for me.