# WPF DataContext in ToolTip

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, tooltip, datacontext

I'm trying to bind the tooltip of a ListBoxItem. I have this defined in my ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <conv:IconConverter x:Key="IconConverter" />
        <conv:FirstImageConverter x:Key="FirstImageConverter"/>
        <conv:DebugConverter x:Key="dbg"/>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
<Border ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image MaxHeight="160" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding Icon,Converter={StaticResource IconConverter},ConverterParameter=128}" Height="128"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblName" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Border.ToolTip>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="2" MaxWidth="800" 
        DataContext="{Binding Images,Converter={StaticResource FirstImageConverter}}" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding Images,Converter={StaticResource FirstImageConverter},ConverterParameter=enabled}">
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="600"  Text="{Binding Caption}" Height="Auto" />
            <Image x:Name="imgFullSize" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Stretch="None" Width="Auto" Source="{Binding Filename,Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border.ToolTip>
```

Yes I get a binding error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides DataContext. BindingExpression:Path=Images; DataItem=null; target element is 'DockPanel' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')`

My ListBoxItem's datacontext does contain the images property as it does the name and icon properties, which are displayed correctly. I've also tried using `TooltipService.ToolTip` instead of `Border.ToolTip`, with no effect. What's the difference, and why isn't my binding working?

Comment: See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755540/302677) (don't have time to write this up as a full answer right now :))

Comment: Thanks Rachel, this led me to the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eventually solved this by changing the tooltip to this:

```
...
<Border.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.Images, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.Images, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Converter={StaticResource FirstImageConverter},ConverterParameter=visible}">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="2" MaxWidth="800">
            ...
```

Thanks @Rachel for leading me to the answer.