# Custom Tool tip on Data Trigger

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tooltip, custom-controls

This is my working `XAML` code for a tooltip:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=txtParent}" Value="Visible">
       <Setter Property="StackPanel.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Text,ElementName=txtParent}" TargetName="PanelTitle">
       </Setter>   
 </DataTrigger>
```

Now I want a tool tip which has maximum width as well as text wrapping. I tried using the following code but it didnt work:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility,ElementName=txtParent}" Value="Visible"> 
     <Setter Property="StackPanel.ToolTip" TargetName="PanelTitle">
           <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                <StackPanel Margin="7,1">                                               
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=txtParent}"  Margin="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"                          Width="200"                         TextWrapping='Wrap' VerticalAlignment="Top" />                                               
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755540/302677) help?

Comment: @Rachel: Where is the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ToolTip` does not exist in the visual tree in the way you might expect.  It does not participate in the inheritance context or the "owner" element's name scope at runtime.  I would guess that your binding is unable to resolve `txtParent` at runtime because it doesn't know where to look.

You could try replacing `ElementName=txtParent` in your binding with `Source={x:Reference txtParent}`, which forces the name to resolve during the parsing stage, when the name will still be in scope.  It may work, and it may not, but either way it will likely break the XAML designer.

Also, you are setting the value of the `ToolTip` to a `ControlTemplate`, which doesn't make much sense.  You should probably be setting it to a `ToolTip` instance (or some other content type):

```
<Setter.Value>
  <ToolTip>
    <StackPanel Margin="7,1" >                                               
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,Source={x:Reference txtParent}}"
                 Margin="1"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Width="200"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </StackPanel>
  </ToolTip>
</Setter.Value>
```

Another hack which *might* work is to store the `ToolTip` as a resource somewhere in scope and have your `Setter` assign it with a `StaticResource` reference.  Generally, using UI elements as shared resources is error prone and considered bad practice, but seeing as only one `ToolTip` should ever be loaded at any given  time in your application, it may work:

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
  <ToolTip x:Key="MyToolTip">
    <StackPanel Margin="7,1" >                                               
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,Source={x:Reference txtParent}}"
                 Margin="1"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Width="200"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </StackPanel>
  </ToolTip>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>

<!-- ... -->

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=txtParent}"
             Value="Visible">
  <Setter Property="StackPanel.ToolTip"
          Value="{StaticResource MyToolTip}"
          TargetName="PanelTitle" />
</DataTrigger>
```

If you are using MVVM, though, the easiest (and probably best) thing to do would be to bind `txtParent.Text` to a property on your view model; then you could use [the technique from this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755540/302677) to bind to the same property for your `ToolTip`.

Comment: Hey Thanks!!! As rightly pointed out by you , the first piece of code breaks the XAML designer. And the second one says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Any help?

Comment: The `ToolTip` resource may need to be declared *after* the `txtParent` element in XAML.  Can you shift your resource declarations around and see if that helps?  I tested my examples in Kaxaml, and they both worked (except that I didn't have a `TargetName` in my `Setter`).

Comment: I changed Source={x:Reference txtParent} to Element Name, It gave no error . But now it says the resource MyToolTip cannot be resolved.Even though I changed the declaration of ToolTip after the txtParent.

Comment: Are you using MVVM?  This would be easier if your `TextBox.Text` was data-bound to a property on your view model; then you could use [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755540/302677) to bind to the same property for your `ToolTip`.

Comment: No Im not using MVVM, Basic Over view is : <usercontrol.resources><style><setter.value><<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=txtParent}"
             Value="Visible">
  <Setter Property="StackPanel.ToolTip"
          Value="{StaticResource MyToolTip}"
          TargetName="PanelTitle" />
</DataTrigger></setter.value></style><tooltip>..</tooltip></usercontrol.resources>

Comment: The `ToolTip` resource has to be declared before the `Style` with the `DataTrigger` referencing it.  And I suspect `<UserControl.Resources>` has to be declared *after* `txtParent` too.

Comment: Problem is my txtParent is defined in the style itself!!!. Any way to do it?Output shows no data in the tool tip.

Comment: Put the resources under `Style.Resources` at the end of the `Style` declaration?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46765/discussion-between-zooney-and-mike-strobel)

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow chat is blocked at my office :(.