# Find ancestor in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, devexpress, datatemplate

I'm trying to show popup on `DataTemplate` element `TextEdit` (from [DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsTextEdittopic)), according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619868/how-can-i-display-a-tooltip-constantly-while-a-control-is-focused) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789090/bind-to-a-property-in-the-parent-control) topics I created something like that:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate">
    <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="SomeTextEdit" Text="{Binding DisplayText, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    EditMode="InplaceInactive">
        <dxe:TextEdit.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu/>
        </dxe:TextEdit.ContextMenu>
        <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxe:TextEdit}}}" IsOpen="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxe:TextEdit}}, Mode=OneWay}">
            <TextBlock Background="White">
                <TextBlock.Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </Popup>
    </dxe:TextEdit>
</DataTemplate>
```

And it don't work, in Diagnostic Tool Events window I get message:

```
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.TextEdit', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'Popup' (Name=''); target property is 'PlacementTarget' (type 'UIElement')
```

Why is that?

Comment: Looks like you might want `RelativeSource Self` here -- have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Popup` will use different `VisualTree` and we cannot use RelativeSource binding method to find element from main `VisualTree`.Still you can set `PlacementTarget` via `ElementName` binding. You can use like this,

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding PlacementTarget.IsKeyboardFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},Mode=OneWay}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=SomeTextEdit}">
    <TextBlock Background="White" Text="Hi" />
</Popup>
```