# How absolutely set ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I need set to all app `ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty = 10000`

this anwser HCL

```
 <Style TargetType="Control"> 
     <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="10000"/>
</Style>
```

this Good. However, it must add the items to add style. You can not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following in your Application.Resources-section if you App.xaml-file:

```
<Style TargetType="Control">
     <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="10000"/>
</Style>
```

If control is not strong enough, try it with FrameworkElement. Take care, if you define your own styles. In this case derive from this style or put the setter also there in.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but overriding the default value works brilliantly (as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8308254/762688) elsewhere on stack)

```
ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(DependencyObject), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(60000));
```

Hope it helps...