# How to snoop a tooltip using Snoop?

Tags: .net, wpf, snoop

Is there a trick for snooping a tooltip? Since it disappears as soon as the mouse gets over it there is no chance for ctrl+shift+click.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change code, you can write a simple code that prevents tooltip close, and then you can snoop it.

Take a look to this: 
[Forcing a WPF tooltip to stay on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896574/forcing-a-wpf-tooltip-to-stay-on-the-screen)

Comment: StaysOpen is always true -- even after I managed to get the mouse pointer over the tooltip itself (after setting IsOpen manually from within Snoop) I have no chance to see=snoop the actual visual tree of the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `ToolTip` property on every element in the visual tree, so just navigate the visual tree via snoop until you find it at look at the `ToolTip` property - no ?

Comment: Xaml is like `<FrameworkElement.ToolTip><ToolTip Content="{Binding SomeProp}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource template}" ...` -- sometimes the tooltip spans entire height of screen without any useful content, but the very same DataTemplate works well at other places, that's why I wanted to snoop the real visual tree; and there currently is none.